# ¿Es correcto usar "es decir" después de un punto y seguido?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, redacción

Tengo una frase larga (cuatro líneas). Dentro de ella, tengo un "es decir". ¿Es correcto que coloque punto y seguido antes de "Es decir"? De esta manera tendría oraciones más cortas.

> Uno de los problemas más graves del proceso mencionado es la alta dimensionalidad del espacio de términos. Es decir, el conjunto de términos es muy grande, pero...

Comment: Me gusta como dividiste el texto en dos oraciones separadas, porque si no, quedaría muy denso.

Answer (score 7):

Sí, sí es correcto.

Por lo que indica el DPD en su artículo *[coma](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=V1EqcYbX4D61AWBBrd)*, las comas son obligatorias tras la expresión, pero no antes. Antes son solo obligatorias si la expresión *es decir* va en medio de la oración. Pero puede perfectamente ir al principio.

> 1.2.11. **Se escribe coma detrás de determinados enlaces como** *esto es*, ***es decir***, *a saber*, *pues bien*, *ahora bien*, *en primer lugar*, *por un/otro lado*, *por una/otra parte*, *en fin*, *por último*, *además*, *con todo*, *en tal caso*, *sin embargo*, *no obstante*, *por el contrario*, *en cambio* y otros similares, así como detrás de muchos adverbios o locuciones adverbiales que modifican a toda la oración y no solo a uno de sus elementos, como *efectivamente*, *generalmente*, *naturalmente*, *por regla general*, etc.: *Por lo tanto, los que no tengan invitación no podrán entrar al recinto; no obstante, podrán seguir el acto a través de pantallas instaladas en el exterior. Naturalmente, los invitados deben vestir de etiqueta*. **Si estas expresiones van en medio de la oración, se escriben entre comas**: *Estas palabras son sinónimas, es decir, significan lo mismo; los antónimos, en cambio, tienen significados opuestos*.

Buscando en el CORDE (textos desde los inicios del español hasta 1974) resultados de *Es decir* (nótese que se pone la primera *E* mayúscula, dado que la búsqueda distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas), se encuentran 2325 casos, y en el CREA (textos desde 1975 hasta 2004) se encuentran 8189 casos.

Ejemplos (negritas mías):

> *...y juntamente con esto la sazón del verano, que es tiempo fresco y apacible, y muy aparejado para tratar amores, y ansí dice, levántate. **Es decir**, levántate, se entiende, que estaba acostada y mal dispuesta, y ansí dícele, que se esfuerce y se salga con él...*
>
> Fray Luis de León, "Exposición del Cantar de los Cantares", c 1561 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Los expertos consideran que, ante esta situación, los precios de venta al público podrían aumentar en las próximas semanas entre dos y tres céntimos de euro más por litro, con lo que la subida del año podría situarse en el 8%. **Es decir**, más del triple que la inflación.*
>
> La Voz de Galicia, 15/01/2004 (España).

Comment: Correcto si es, pero por estilo ¿no es mejor usar coma o incluso punto y coma? ¿qué opinas?

Comment: @DGaleano pues la verdad es que no tengo una idea clara al respecto. No creo que una forma suponga un "mejor" estilo con respecto a la otra. Me suenan las dos igual de bien.

Comment: Interesante [debate de Pérez-Reverte](https://twitter.com/perezreverte/status/996819154723360768) sobre el uso de _es decir_ después de punto y coma o entre comas.