# ¿Cómo se puede traducir "one-class classification" al español?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

En el contexto de clasificación de textos, ¿Cómo se puede traducir "one-class classification" al español?

Por ejemplo:

> In the problem of one-class classification (OCC) one of the classes, the target class, has to be distinguished from all other possible objects, considered as nontargets.

Intentaba traducirlo como "una clase contra el resto del mundo", pero parece que no es una traducción adecuada.

Comment: Por ejemplo, no sería mal mencionar que en inglés también tiene el nombre de «unary classification», término que debe tener una traducción facilísima

Comment: Marie, parece que tienes dos cuentas: esta y la que creó [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22393/1674). Si es así, lee [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) para intentar juntarlas.

Comment: Gracias, lo revisaré

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por lo que leo, parece ser un término de *machine learning*, y tiene también otro nombre que es *"unary classification"*.

*"Unary classification"* es, como dice @guifa, fácilmente traducible a, por ejemplo, **"clasificación unitaria"**. Hay [publicaciones de ML en español [PDF]](http://paginaspersonales.deusto.es/isantos/papers/2013/2013-Nieves-Meta.pdf) que lo usan así.

*"One-class clasification"* lo podrías traducir como **"clasificación de clase única"**; o, si quieres imitar al inglés, "clasificación [uni](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b4jMgXW)clase" (forma que no recomiendo en absoluto).